# How can I get the value of the EC2 instance tag "Name" with boto?

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto

I'm working from the instance id. I can get the tags, but I can't figure out how filter on both the instance id and the tag "Name" or index in and return the value of the tag called "Name"

I ended up grabbing all tags and iterating over them till I find the one I want, which can't possibly be right.

```
 tags = conn.get_all_tags({'resource-id': instance_id})
  for tag in tags:
    if 'Name' in tag.name:
      name = tag.value
```

Comment: Does the code above work?

Comment: Yes, it just seems like a very roundabout way to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do have a better way:

```
conn.get_all_tags(filters={'tag-key': 'Name', 'resource-id': instance_id})
```

Comment: Thanks, was having trouble with the syntax of a multiple factor filter.

Comment: No problem, if you want to get more info about multiple factor filters, take a look at this link - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html @jorfus

Answer (score 0):

I think the way you're doing it is fine. You could always wrap it in a function call as an abstraction:

```
def get_instance_tag(all_tags, tag_name):
  for tag in all_tags:
    if tag_name == tag.name:
      return tag.value

  return None

name = get_instance_tag(conn.get_all_tags({'resource-id': instance_id}), 'Name')
```

Note that `if tag_name == tag.name:` is more accurate than `if tag_name in tag.name:`.